# Identify beamer theme

Tags: beamer, formatting, themes

[image: screenshot of page from beamer presentation]

I am trying to identify what theme (if any) was used to create this beamer presentation. [This](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/TALKS/enet_talk.pdf) is the entire file.

Comment: Probably an own definition/own theme. What exactly do you want to imitate?

Comment: That was my suspicion... I'd like to get that same drop shadow effect, but I don't know an elegant way of doing it. (maybe colorbox can do something similar? )

Comment: Have a look at `tcolorbox`. It has a great manual. Just search for "shadow".

Comment: Thanks, I might play around with that. I like the minimal look of this document though compared to most of what's common with `tcolorbox`

Comment: Why? `tcolorbox` can also be very minimal. You just have to use the right settings.

Comment: It looks like `seminar` slides with `shadowbox`-es (from [`fancybox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancybox))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it seems that OP is only worried by the shadowbox, here there are two ways of doing them. What I think is the original `shadowbox` from `fancybox` package and a `tcbox` (from `tcolorbox`) trying to mimic them (both work with `beamer`):

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\newtcbox{\tshadowbox}[1][]{%
   enhanced,
    colframe=red,
    colback=white,
    sharp corners,
    colupper=red,
    notitle,
    shadow={1.5mm}{-1.5mm}{0mm}{red, opacity=1},
    size=fbox,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\tshadowbox{\texttt{tcolorbox tshadowbox}}
\medskip

{\color{red}\shadowbox{\texttt{fancybox shadowbox}}}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Probably should have figured this out myself, but your solutions are very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the pdf properties (https://i.stack.imgur.com/94t0C.png) I doubt that this was made with beamer, but you can easily do something similar with beamer:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, drop shadow=red,enhanced,colback=white,colframe=red, sharp corners=all]
\insertframetitle
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{size=\small}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vskip0.7em\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\hspace*{1em}\insertshorttitle\hfill\insertshortauthor\hfill\insertframenumber\hspace*{1em}\vskip0.7em}

\title{title}
\author{author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\begin{itemize}
\item content
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]